Laravel 11 @yield not displaying
I am trying to use the @yield directive in my blade view to display content.
I've followed the Laravel documentation but it is simply not displaying my content.
resources/views/layouts/home.blade.php
...
<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>
...

resources/views/layouts/content.blade.php
@extends('home')
@section('content')
<p>This is my content</p>
@endsection

Both blade views are in the same folder.
If I use the @include directive it does work, but that's not what I'm after.
Thanks.

Would @extends('layouts.home') work?

It doesn't. I've also tried @yield('layouts.content') and every other combination.

How do you call your content view?

My controller: return view('layouts.home');
So it's not actually returning the child view directly... I was under the impression that if you return the parent view, it will yield the children when it is rendered. Is this right?

No. You use return view('layouts.content');, which in turn @extends('layouts.home').

Ahh that is working. Thank you! It seems my understanding is wrong... I have a view that is getting very long, so I want to break it up into separate blade views, and use yield directives to display each child inside the main view. Should I be using @include instead?

Yes, split your long view in different smaller ones, @include them where you need them. Or use Blade components

Today I encountered the same issue - @yield doesn't work.
